# joomla front-end HTTP error 500 (white page displaying on index page)

Tags: joomla, indexing, frontend

i ve got a problem with my joomla 2.5.4 front-end it display always a whie page even the server php version is 5.4 but the backoffice still running. it happened suddenly and the problem am not the developper am just charged to solve this problem! so please if anyone have an idea what happends and how to solve this problem
this the link to the web site : http://www.worldsafaritravel.com/ if any one can help ? thanks

Comment: 500 error could mean anything related on your server, from the misconfiguration till the code problems. That's really tough to diagnose just right like this.

Comment: you meant other browsers, it is generally the same 500 error, but without user notification, I would start with checking out custom extenstions on your homepage

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14152801/server-error-500/14152851#14152851 put this code in your index.php .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try renaming the .htaccess file (and disable sef in configuration if you see the homepage). so you can see if it's an access-related problem.

Otherwise see the error logs, make backups as you proceed.

One blind try could be to install the updated files of the latest version of joomla 2.5.9 http://joomlacode.org/gf/download/frsrelease/17967/78437/Joomla_2.5.9-Stable-Update_Package.zip  just copying them over the installation, it's just a wild guess, you see it's not likely that you can find a solution without looking at the error logs.

Keep a copy of the original files, you don't know if they were changed.

Comment: thx body as u said it was a problem in my htaccess file an SSL...
thk u all bros hope help ya back :)